# App-V Virtual Process and local filesystem?

Tags: windows, appv

I run this code in powershell:

```
$AppVName = Get-AppvClientPackage <Package>
Start-AppvVirtualProcess -AppvClientObject $AppVName cmd.exe
```

then i write file with cmd command; the file is persisted on host filesystem. Is this normal behavior, i thought that virtual processes is run in some kind of "bubble" ?

How do i enable this bubble so that files written by virtual processes are not persisted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the [correct methods](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2848278/how-to-launch-processes-inside-the-app-v-5-0-virtualized-environment) to run inside an app-v container.

Is the file that you're modifying/writing **is in a path that is part of the original VFS structure of your app-v package**, or are you saving it in another folder from the machine?

If the cmd.exe process is modifying files that are not present in the VFS folders from the app-v package it is normal for those files to persist on the machine.

*You can check the VFS folder structure from app-v package by unzipping with 7-zip.*

Comment: I save it in another folder on machine such as desktop folder. When i get cmd.exe shell i can write files which are persisted on the system even when virtual process exits. If cmd.exe run in virtual process container can do it , then the virtual app can do the same, right?